# Mailmessage 4.0 work in framework 3.0

Tags: c#, mailmessage, .net-3.0

I have one class, work in framework 4.0, but not work in framework 3.0.
I need this working in framework 3.0.

I need help for work in 3.0 framework it is possible?

```
  public void EnviarEmail(string Titulo)
  {
      MensagemEmail.To.Clear();
      MensagemEmail.To.Add(EmailEnviar);
      MensagemEmail.From = EmailOrigem;
      MensagemEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
      MensagemEmail.Subject = Titulo;
      MensagemEmail.Body = Mensagem.ToString();
      MensagemEmail.ReplyToList.Add(EmailOrigem);
      this.Servidor.Send(MensagemEmail);
  }


  public void Dispose()
  {
      EmailEnviar = null;
      EmailOrigem = null;
      Mensagem.Clear();
      Mensagem = null;
      MensagemEmail.To.Clear();
      MensagemEmail.Dispose();
      MensagemEmail = null;
      Servidor.Dispose();
      Servidor = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, "doesn't work"?

Comment: To be clear, there is nothing listed in this code which would not work under the .Net Framework 3.0. (I'm amazed you can find a machine running this; perhaps .Net 3.5?) In fact, I cannot see anything about this code snipped which would not run on .Net Framework 1.1.

Comment: MensagemEmail.ReplyToList.Add(EmailOrigem);

Comment: Servidor.Dispose(); not compile

Answer (score 0):

The ReplyToList property isn't used in the Framework3.0 version of the MailMessage class.

Here's the [MSDN System.Net.Mail Namespace page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.mail%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Framework 3.0.  From there you can find the equivalent properties/methods that you need, since it's hard to decipher all the classes you're using.

Comment: look this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/pt-BR/dc500b70-6f1f-4697-9b72-a91864a8737e/from-da-classe-mailmessage-no-funciona-como-esperado don't work in framework 3.0

Comment: Like I said look through the 3.0 version of the namespace and find the equivalents you need